# The child routes in feature module routes is not working in angular 8 and going to page not found page

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8, angular-routing

I have created a product module as a featured module and shift all child routes of the featured module in the product module from 'app-routing.module.ts'. I haven't added lazy loading yet. But after separating product routes the child routes are not working. The routes are redirecting to the pagenotfound routes.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes:Routes=[
  {path:'',redirectTo:'/home',pathMatch:'full'},
  {path:'home',component:HomeComponent},
  {path:'about',component:AboutComponent},
  {path:'product',component:ProductComponent},
  {path:'contact',component:ContactComponent},
  {path:'buy product',component:ParentComponent},
  {path:'view',component:ViewchildComponent},
  {path:"**", component:PageNotFoundComponent}
];
@NgModule({
  imports:[RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{ enableTracing: false })],
  exports:[RouterModule]

})
```

**app.component.html**

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar ngClass = "tabs">
  <a mat-tab-link routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a>
  <a mat-tab-link routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="active-link">About US</a>
  <a mat-tab-link routerLink="/product" routerLinkActive="active-link">Products</a>
  <a mat-tab-link routerLink="/contact" routerLinkActive="active-link">Contact Us</a>
  <a mat-tab-link routerLink="/buy product" routerLinkActive="active-link">Buy Product</a>
  <a mat-tab-link routerLink="/view" routerLinkActive="active-link">View Child</a>
  
</nav>  
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**product.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { LatopComponent } from './latop/latop.component';
import { MobileComponent } from './mobile/mobile.component';
import { ComputerComponent } from './computer/computer.component';
import { MachineComponent } from './machine/machine.component';
 import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import { ProductComponent } from './product.component';
import { MaterialModule } from '../material/material.module';

const proRoute:Routes=[ {path:'product',children:[
  {path:'',component:ProductComponent},
  {path:'laptop', component:LatopComponent},
  {path:'mobile',component:MobileComponent},
  {path:'computer',component:ComputerComponent},
  {path:'wahing machine',component:MachineComponent}
]}]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ 
    ProductComponent,
    LatopComponent,
    MobileComponent,
    ComputerComponent,
    MachineComponent
    
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
   MaterialModule,
   RouterModule.forChild(proRoute)
    
  ]
  
})
export class ProductModule { }
```

**product.component.html**

```
<a routerLink='/laptop' mat-raised-button color="primary">Know Laptop</a>
<a routerLink='/mobile' mat-raised-button color="primary">Know Mobile</a>
<a routerLink='/computer' mat-raised-button color="primary">Know Computer</a>
<a routerLink='/wahing machine' mat-raised-button color="primary">Know Washing Machine</a>
```

Comment: Can you please share the way you solved the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like both your AppRoutingModule and your ProductModule are registering a `product` route. Remove the one from your AppRoutingModule and the route registration should work.

(Also make sure that your ProductModule is imported in your AppModule, remembering that you will have to remove it once you've set up lazy loading.)

Comment: When I am removing the product module from the app-routing module, then the product module route is not working and the product module is also imported to AppModule